# Count number of paths among points in N-dimention grid?

Tags: path, count

How to count number of paths between two points in an N-dimension grid?

I know that this can be done in a NxN grid using the formula (x'+y')C(x') where x' and y' are the difference between the x and y coordinates of two points.

I m interested in a extension of above formula to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

For two dimensions, read up on Catalan numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). Note that the formula assumes monotonic paths.

Comment: i m interested in a general formula which can apply on any dimention. and catalan number can count the paths which do not cross the diagonal connecting the point....i m interested in counting all the points among two point.